# Individual Checkbox on HTML Table

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

I am currently displaying my HTML data through a PHP script into my Table on the Website.
No here's the problem: I want to have a checkbox besides every entry on the website, the user can then check or uncheck the checkbox, his decision is then sent via a submit button. But in my PHP script i dont think im able to create an individual checkbox for every entry so that my Script knows which assignment is done or not done.
I hope this makes any sense, if not feel free to ask.
My Code:

````
<tr>
<th style="color:aliceblue">Fach</th>
<th style="color:aliceblue">Name</th>
<th style="color:aliceblue">Abgabedatum</th>
    <th style="color:aliceblue">Erledigt</th>

</tr>
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306", "xnmmgfa1_Lernjournal", "Lernjournal2021", "xnmmgfa1_LJ");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT Fach, Name, Abgabedatum FROM Lernauftraege";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td style='text-align: center;color:antiquewhite;'>" . $row["Fach"]. "</td><td style='text-align: center; color:antiquewhite;'>" . $row["Name"] ."</td><td  style='text-align: center; color:antiquewhite;'>"
. $row["Abgabedatum"].  "</td><td style='text-align: center; color:antiquewhite;'>" . "<input type='checkbox' id'erledigt' name='$id'>" . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else { echo "0 results"; }
$conn->close();
?>
    <button type="submit" name="b_erledigt">Senden</button>     
</table>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array notation as input name.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="userselection[]" value="$row['id']"/>
```

And in your PHP code that handles the submitted form

```
$userselection = $_POST['userselection'];
foreach ($userselection as $selectedId) { 
  /* whatever you wanna do with the selected rows... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i added your code into the table but now i get an error with the VALUE statement, `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td style='text-align: center;color:antiquewhite;'>" . $row["Fach"]. "</td><td style='text-align: center; color:antiquewhite;'>" . $row["Name"] ."</td><td  style='text-align: center; color:antiquewhite;'>"
. $row["Abgabedatum"].  "</td><td style='text-align: center; color:antiquewhite;'>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='userselection[]' value='$row["id"]'/>" . "</td></tr>";` I get a quotation error, ive tried every method of quotation

Comment: Here the error @Martin: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected double-quote mark, expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number in /home/xnmmgfa1/lernjournal.com/Auftrage.php on line 91

Comment: @MikkaKummer You can *not* use double quotes inside a double quoted string! `"<input type='checkbox' name='userselection[]' value='" . $row['id'] . "'/>"` should fix this error.